# Yii: помогите с разбором кода

Tags: php, yii

Из чистого любопытства пытаюсь понять, как работают реляционные Active Records
Например есть две таблицы в разных базах.
Таблица object из БД-1 имеет поле device_id.
Таблица device из БД-2 имеет поле id.
Есть модель Object, в ней определенна связь с моделью Device.

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'device' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Device', 'id'))
}
```

При запросе

```
var_dump($object->device);
```

всё работает.
Вопрос: как yii определяет какую именно запись дернуть из бд, если у таблиц нет внешних ключей и лежат они в разных базах?
Как или где в коде определяется что **Object::device_id** соответствует **Device::id** ?

**P.s.** Теория тоже хорошо, но код всё же лучше. Просто ткните носом где смотреть. Сам пока не разобрался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как помнится по умолчанию

```
'device' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Device', 'id'))
```

из object возьмется id и найдется по id в device

можно явно указать что да где искать

```
'device'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Device',array('device_id'=>'id')),
```

типа взять из таблицы **object** поле **device_id** и поискать совпадения в таблице **device** в поле  **id**

Comment: @Shrek Спасибо, но мне как раз хочется найти тот кусок кода, где выясняется что поле device_id соответствует полю id

Comment: Эм, глаза открой, я тебе написал какое поле из какой таблицы.

Comment: @Shrek да кажется начинаю понимать.  
Похоже выхватывается первичный ключ первой таблицы и ищется его совпадение в указанном поле. В общем-то повторил ваш ответ своими словами.  
Если найду кусок кода, который меня интересует, выложу.