# Отношение таблиц в базе

Tags: yii, php, php-frameworks, mysqli

Есть три таблицы

```
Device {
  id_device:primary key,
  name,
  id_type
}

DevicePc {
  id_device_pc,
  mb,
  cpu,
  ram
}

DeviceType {
  id_device_type,
  type
}
```

Т.е. есть некое устройство Device, если это устройство РС, то заполняется DeviceРC и у каждого устройства есть тип из таблицы DeviceType. Не могу создать связь между Device и DeviceРC.

Пишу так:

```
class Device extends CActiveRecord{
    public function relations()
        {
            return array(
                'devicepc' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'DevicePc', 'id_device'),
                'devicetype' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'DeviceType', 'id_type'),           
            );
        }
    }

class DevicePc extends CActiveRecord{
  public function relations(){
           return array(
         'device' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Device', 'id_device_pc'),
        );
    }
}

class DeviceType extends CActiveRecord{
   public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'device' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Device', 'id_device_type'),
        );
    }
}
```

Связь между Device и DeviceType есть а с DevicePc нет.

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'devicepc.' in 'on clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `t`.`id_device` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`id_organization` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`id_branch` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`id_department` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`id_cabinet` AS `t0_c4`, `t`.`id_employee` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`id_type` AS `t0_c6`, `t`.`name` AS `t0_c7`, `t`.`description` AS `t0_c8`, `t`.`inv_number` AS `t0_c9`, `t`.`sn` AS `t0_c10`, `t`.`year` AS `t0_c11`, `t`.`end_varantly_yesr` AS `t0_c12`, `t`.`service` AS `t0_c13`, `t`.`expluatation` AS `t0_c14`, `t`.`expluatation_data` AS `t0_c15`, `t`.`private` AS `t0_c16`, `t`.`break` AS `t0_c17`, `devicepc`.`id_device_pc` AS `t1_c0`, `devicepc`.`mb` AS `t1_c1`, `devicepc`.`cpu_name` AS `t1_c2`, `devicepc`.`cpu_p` AS `t1_c3`, `devicepc`.`hdd_name` AS `t1_c4`, `devicepc`.`hdd_p` AS `t1_c5`, `devicepc`.`ram_name` AS `t1_c6`, `devicepc`.`ram_p` AS `t1_c7`, `devicepc`.`video_name` AS `t1_c8`, `devicepc`.`video_p` AS `t1_c9`, `devicepc`.`cdrom_name` AS `t1_c10`, `devicepc`.`lan_name` AS `t1_c11`, `devicepc`.`os` AS `t1_c12`, `devicepc`.`net_name` AS `t1_c13`, `devicepc`.`ip` AS `t1_c14`, `devicetype`.`id_device_type` AS `t2_c0`, `devicetype`.`name` AS `t2_c1`, `devicetype`.`description` AS `t2_c2` FROM `t_devices` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `t_device_pc` `devicepc` ON (`t`.`id_device`=`devicepc`.``) LEFT OUTER JOIN `t_devices_types` `devicetype` ON (`t`.`id_type`=`devicetype`.`id_device_type`)
```

Почему в этом условии пусто? Что я сделал не так?

```
t_device_pc` `devicepc` ON (`t`.`id_device`=`devicepc`.``)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Вопрос - БД MySql и тип таблиц MyIsam?
2. Почему не использовать InnoDB с внешними ключами?
3. Gii генератор создаст необходимые связи сам
4. + Ко всему целостность данных будет намного выше.

Ну а если так-то нужно сказать в relations, какое поле из таблицы Device, и какое поле из таблицы Devicepc должны быть связаны.

Если воспользоваться поиском по форуму, то я уже отвечал на подобный вопрос.

**//upd**

[Это не ваш вопрос случаем?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/235692/php-yii-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)  Однотипно прям 1:1

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
Еще добавлю что у меня в таблице Devicepc нет поля первичного ключа, поэтому и по внешнему ключу связь не работала. Добавил поле id:PK и всё заработало. Спасибо

Comment: @Дмитрий Галушко, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).